# onPress React navigation doesn't work for component inside Stacknavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, stack-navigator

Hey guys for the Stacknavigator I made a component  and placed this in the headerRight of navigation options because I can only show one Icon there.
 is just a view with three icons in it. However when i try to do an onPress with the props.navigation.navigate function I get an error saying undefined is not an object this.props.navigation.navigate. How can i work around this?

`export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Tabs,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#a3a5ab',
            },
            headerRight: <Headericons /> } },`

class Headericons extends React.Component {

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}


Shoppingcart= () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Shoppingcart');
};


render() {

    return (
        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginRight: 10}}>
          <TouchableWithoutFeedback
              onPress={()=> this.Shoppingcart() } >


            <Icon
                name={'shopping-cart'}
                size={30}
                color={'#ffffff'}
                style={{marginRight: 0, paddingRight: 10, flexDirection: 'row'}}

            />
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to pass `navigation` through to the component.

```
export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Tabs,
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#a3a5ab',
            },
            headerRight: <Headericons navigation={navigation} />
        })
    },
})
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. What do you mean exactly? I tried doing it like this but it still doesn't work.

``const navigation = this.props.navigation.navigate();``

``export const HomeStack = StackNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: Tabs,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: '#a3a5ab',

            },
            headerRight: <Headericons navigation={navigation}  />``

Comment: Have edited my answer with a more complete code example

Comment: For additional details, check the docs at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options#Screen-Navigation-Options

Comment: I've made a further edit to fix a syntax error where I missed () around the object being returned from the fat arrow function

Comment: Hmm still no luck. Can i send you my code via git stash?

Comment: I got it. I had to do this
``navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
  headerRight: <Headericons navigation={navigation} />
})``